# Capturing Click event using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am  able to capture click event any where on my form but there is an Iframe on my page when I click on that it doesn't get capture.

here is a code.

```
document.onclick = function(e) { alert(e.clientX + "|" + e.clientY); }
```

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Iframe's won't "bubble up" their click events to the parent window. You would have to put something similar on the Iframe page, like this:

```
document.onclick = function(e) { 
  if (window.parent.iframeClicked) {
    window.parent.iframeClicked(e);
  }
}
```

and then define the `iframeClicked` function on your parent window:

```
function iframeClicked(e) {
  /* your code here */
}
```

Comment: good point about cross-domain security though - it will definitely not work if the iframe loads a page from a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

BreakHead,

As long as the frame is on your own domain, you could try:

```
<body onclick="parent.handleClickEvent(event)">
```

if it's a frame from another site, then the same domain policy won't allow access, in which case Google "javascript cross domain security"